# Dynmically add arguments to queryset filter call in django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a list of strings, which will be generated dynamically. So it will be of variable length:

```
keywords = ['apples','oranges','bananas']
```

I have a model Fruitsalad, with a  field 'description'. Lets say I want to find all Fruitsalads with either 'apples', 'oranges' or 'bananas' in the 'description' field

```
results = Fruitsalad.objects.filter(Q(description__icontains=keywords[0]) | Q(description__icontains=keywords[1] | Q(description__icontains=keywords[2])
```

How could I generate the above query when I don't know in advance how long the 'keywords' list will be?

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over your array, and do a union on each result

```
allresults = Fruitsalad.objects.all()
keywords = ['apples','oranges','bananas']
queryset = None
for keyword in keywords:
    if queryset == None:
        queryset = allresults.filter(description__icontains=keyword)
    else:
        queryset = queryset.union(allresults.filter(description__icontains=keyword))

#here are the desired results
print(queryset)
```